# Ruby 1.8.7: Enumerator next complains about number of arguments

Tags: ruby, enumerator, ruby-1.8.7

When I do the following in Ruby 1.9.3 (also JRuby, Rubinius...), it works as expected:

```
enum = [1,2,3,4,5].each
#=> #<Enumerator: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]:each>
enum.next
#=> 1
```

If I try the same thing on Ruby 1.8.7 with backports, the following thing happens:

```
require "backports"
enum = [1,2,3,4,5].each
#=> #<Enumerable::Enumerator:0x1057fd400>
enum.next
#=> ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)
```

What am I doing wrong here? I don't give any arguments as far as I know.

*Clarification:* It does not happen without back ports

Comment: works for me: `>> p VERSION; enum = [1,2,3,4,5].each; p enum.next
#=> "1.8.7" 1`

Comment: @tokland Thanks for the input. Please see the clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this is a bug in backports. I reported it.